# Running script without adding it to the HTML

Tags: javascript

In one of my project, I need to do a "custom" script inside my script. It is working, here a small example:

```
var object = {test : 10};

var script = document.createElement('script');

var condition = $('div').data('if');

script.innerHTML = 
    'function runIf(){\
        with(object){ \
            try{\
                return '+condition+'? true : false;\
            }catch(err){\
                console.log(err.message);\
                return false;\
            }\
        }\
    }';

document.body.appendChild(script)

$('div').toggle(runIf());

document.body.removeChild(script)
```

Im getting the condition on a DOM element like this :

```
<div data-if='test>0'>test</div>
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nb234/2/

But now, I want to know if I can have the same result without appending something to the HTML. Can't I create a script tag (or a function in a string form) and run it?

**EDIT:**

I've done an other example, hope it will help to understand : http://jsfiddle.net/nb234/4/

Comment: You mean you have a legitimate use of `eval(code)`?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you did in your sample code... Why not just create a `function runIf() {...}` inside your code, use it in the `toggle` call and then assign `runIf = null`?

Comment: @Brian im trying to use `eval()`, but cant get anything to work. @Steve, I need to check the condtion who's inserted by the user inside a data in the DOM, there can be multiple DOM element with a `data-if` and it can contain a complex condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
eval(string_with_code);
```

to execute your string function.

Comment: How can i use eval wtih `with(object)`? With is really important in my case.

Comment: What looks like the "condition" variable? why is "with" so important?

Comment: Cause it check the condition with the variable in the `var object`, but if it `object.test` doesnt exist, it will check if `test` is a global variable.

Comment: Maybe: script.innerHTML = 
        'function runIf(){\
                return object.'+condition+'? true : false;\
            }';

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nb234/3/)

Comment: Then, if the var is a global var, the condition will fail.

Comment: `with(object){ if(test){} }` don't check if `test` is a global variable. neither my `"object."+condition` solution, can you explain me a little bit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38200/discussion-between-pipe-and-karl-andre-gagnon)

Comment: Declare a unique function and eval only the expresion: http://jsfiddle.net/nb234/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly run a script without adding it to the `<body>` element: add it to the `<head>` element instead.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Snarkiness aside, adding the element to the DOM is the preferred method of dynamically loading scripts, which is why tools such as jQuery's `$.getScript` and requirejs insert new `<script>` elements into the DOM.

You could certainly remove the script from the DOM after inserting it, but it's not really necessary.

Comment: Well i missexplained myself :) I want to know if i can run the code without inserting it in the HTML. Also, the script change since there is multiple DOM element with the `data-if` attribut.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect place to take advantage of javascripts first class functions.  Instead of storing a string containing javascript just store an actual javascript function in the data and use it as a predicate.

```
function runIf(predicate) {
    return predicate() ? true : false;
}

function pred() {
    return 1==1;
}

alert(runIf(pred) );
```

Note: The use of with is discouraged https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: I know with is discouraged but in my case, it doesnt matter, it actually do exactly what i want (talking about the second cons). IT is actually important that i use `with`. Also, you code doesnt use the data-attribute.

Comment: The above was an example of the pattern you should be using.  Unfortunately, your code is structured poorly.  You should not be storing strings of javascript in the data of the div.

Comment: I am trying to do a plug-in for not advanced user. The easier it is for the user to use it, the better it is. If the user have to use a complete function in the `data-if` my goal is not achieved.

Answer (score 0):

All your code does is this, which does not require script tags, evals, or with statements.

```
$('div').toggle($('div').data('if'));
```

Comment: That is not what my code does. The user write the HTML and input condition a condition in a `data-if` and it can be like `data-if='myName == "Jay" && myAge == 14'`. It check the condition where `myAge` and `myName` can be either in a defined object created by my code or a custom variable that the user created.